# Jsp Table printed in wrong way

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I have the below code in my jsp. Here in the output the rows are shown as columns and columns are shown as rows.

[image]

```
<%@page import="com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher"%>  
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>  
<body><form action="Export1.jsp" method="post">  
<table border="1px"><TR>  
<%  
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from Scope2");  
    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();  
    int NumOfCol=rsmd.getColumnCount();  
for(int i=1;i<=NumOfCol;i++)  
{%></tr>  

<%  
try  
               {  
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from Scope2");  
    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
       while(rs.next()){  

           %>  
                  <td><%=rs.getString(i)%></td>  
           <%  
       }  

}  
catch(Exception e)  
               {  
    out.println(e);  
}}%>  
   </table><table><tr>  
    <input type="Submit" value="Export"></tr></table></form></body>
```

and the output is as in Screen 1 but i want the output to be as in screen 2. please help me .

Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of this jsp Export1.jsp means ,put his DB logic in Export2.jsp and change action of Export1.jsp also.

Comment: @sunleo: Export1.jsp is for retrieving data but not printing it. in Export1.jsp i'm extracting the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed with the row formatting and the loops. Here is the updated code -

```
<body><form action="Export1.jsp" method="post">  
<table border="1px">  
<%  
    ps=con.prepareStatement("Select * from Scope2");  
    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();  
    int NumOfCol=rsmd.getColumnCount();  

while(rs.next())  
{%>
<TR>
<%  
try  
     {  
       for(int i=1;i<=NumOfCol;i++){  

           %>  
                  <td><%=rs.getString(i)%></td>  
           <%  
       }  

}  
catch(Exception e)  
{  
    out.println(e);  
}
%></TR><%}%>  

</table><table><tr>  
<input type="Submit" value="Export"></tr></table></form></body>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thabk you verymuch mohsin. This is the o/p that i've expected. thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `</tr>` tag at the end of each your `for` loop. So that ay be creating formatting problem.

And why are you executing that query again in the `for` loop while you can use the same `ResultSet rs` that you have obtained earlier ?

Comment: Though i've placed </tr> it is giving the same output

Comment: yes @Rakesh your </tr> should be before </table> tag. You have misplaced it.